# Remove all characters except "all" or "ALL"

Tags: perl

I have string like this

```
$input = "ALL112343" or $input = "all11234" or $input = "ALL 1234"
```

my expect output would be

```
$input = "ALL" or $input = "all"
```

so, how can I remove all the character in that string except the word "all" or "ALL"?

Thank you all for your help,

Comment: *"except certain word"* What is that certain word? Is it always going to be `all` or `ALL`? How do we distinguish the part you want from the part you don't?

Comment: yes, it is always going to be all or ALL

Comment: Why not just write `$input = "ALL"` then?

Comment: So what's wrong with `$input = 'ALL'`?

Comment: because in my case, the user may want to input ALL or all

Comment: What if the user inputs `fall allman`?

Comment: And you need to know the difference? That's a very poor design! See my answer.

Comment: @melpomene: Or even `FALL allman` :)

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
($input) = $input =~ /(all)/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there can only be one occurrence of `all` or `ALL`:

```
$input = $input =~ /(all|ALL)/ ? $1 : "";
```

If there can be multiple occurrences of `all` or `ALL`:

```
$input =~ s/\G(?:all|ALL)*\K.//sg;
```

```
$input = join('', $input =~ /all|ALL/g );
```

It might be more useful to have an array of matches:

```
my @matches = $input =~ /all|ALL/g;
```